# If a function is both upper and lower semicontinuous, does it have to be continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

I am looking for an example of a function which is both upper and lower semi continuous but is not continuous.
I have an example:
$$f(x):=\begin{cases} 1 & \mathrm{if}\; x < 1,\\[7pt]
             2 & \mathrm{if}\; x = 1,\\[7pt]
             \frac{1}{2} & \mathrm{if}\; x > 1. \end{cases}$$
Am I correct ?

Comment: No. Such a function does not exist.

Comment: could you please format the question in a better way?

Comment: What is the nature of the function that I have defined ?

Comment: I'm not able to just read your function, please, format it properly

Comment: @H.D. I know that you are mainly interested in knowing the answer than in formatting your question. But your question is potentially useful to future visitors of this site. For that reason you should take an effort for making it readable. You can put formulas using standard latex sybols (using dollars)

Comment: The function you define in your post seems to have been directly taken from the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-continuity).

Comment: I've formatted his question correctly; he just needs to accept the edit.

Comment: @H.D. See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/282714/upper-semi-continuous-lower-semi-continuous/323773#323773 for a proof

Comment: Sorry brothers/sisters, I am just trying to understand these concepts. I have given a try and only then I have asked, just to know whether I am right or wrong. Thank You Dear brothers/sisters for helping me out. I dont know how to use latex, for that reason I could not format the question properly. I will learn it soon. Thanx.

Comment: No Problem HD !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function is continuous if and only if it is upper and lower semicontinuous.

The function you defined is upper semicontinuous but not lower semicontinuous at $x=1$.

Comment: Excellent answer